Heatmap (seaborn) doesn't show all Ylabels
My heatmap doesn't want to show all Ylabels.
This is the plot

And this is the code
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load the dataset from a file (e.g., 'data.csv')
file_path = 'data.csv'  # Replace with your file path
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='\t')

# Convert the "VAF from Genotyping" column to numeric after removing the percentage sign
df['VAF from Genotyping'] = df['VAF from Genotyping'].str.rstrip('%').astype(float)

# Sort the dataframe by "VAF from Genotyping" in descending order
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by='VAF from Genotyping', ascending=False)

# Modify Sample-Run labels to include #Reads in BAM and VAF from Genotyping
df_sorted["Sample-Run"] = df_sorted["Sample-Run"] + " (" + df_sorted["#Reads in BAM"].astype(str) + " Reads, " + df_sorted["VAF from Genotyping"].astype(str) + "% VAF)"

# Convert detection status to binary
threshold_cols = ["6K", "10K", "15K", "20K", "25K", "35K"]
df_binary = df_sorted[threshold_cols].replace({"No Mutation Detected": 0, "Variant": 1})

# Ensure binary index matches Sample-Run
df_binary.index = df_sorted["Sample-Run"]


print(len(df_binary))

# --- Heatmap Plot ---
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
sns.heatmap(df_binary, cmap="Blues", annot=True, cbar=True, fmt="d")
plt.title("Mutation Detection Matrix Across Thresholds", fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel("Read Thresholds", fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel("Wnumber-RunID Read VAF", fontsize=12)

plt.gca().set_yticklabels(plt.gca().get_yticklabels(), fontsize=10)


# Save heatmap
heatmap_file = "detection_matrix_with_metadata.png"
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig(heatmap_file)
plt.close()  # Close the figure

# Save the sorted dataset to a new file
output_file = 'sorted_data_with_metadata.csv'
df_sorted.to_csv(output_file, index=False, sep='\t')

# Confirmation
print(f"Sorted data saved to '{output_file}'")
print(f"Heatmap saved as '{heatmap_file}'")

The print(len(df_binary)) showed me that the heatmap function takes 54 elements and I can see that in the number of 0s in the first column of the heatmap. However, the plot only show around 27 Ylabels. Why???

sns.heatmap(df_binary, cmap="Blues", annot=True, cbar=True, fmt="d", yticklabels=True)
